# How to test Go code which uses databases(mysql)?

Tags: mysql, testing, go

I have a gRPC service using MySQL and need to clear records after every test case. I try to wrap every test case with a transaction. It works if there's no transaction in my rpc code but fails if there are. And there'll be errors like:

```
can't start transaction
...
sql: Transaction has already been committed or rolled back
```

Then I try to use truncate to clear the records but some of the test cases fails randomly.

My code is like(I use gorm):

```
func foo(db *gorm.DB) {
    tx := db.Begin()
    // query and insert
    tx.Commit()
}
// Use transaction to do database cleanup
func TestFooVersion1() {
    testDB := initDB()
    tx = testDB.Begin() // setup
    foo(testDB)
    tx.Rollback() // teardown
}
// Use truncate to do database cleanup
func TestFooVersion2() {
    testDB := initDB()
    foo(testDB)
    truncateTables(testDB) // teardown
}
func truncateTables(db *gorm.DB) {
    // exec "TRUNCATE TABLE table;" for every table
}
```

What's a proper way to test the code using DB(MySQL)? (I don't like mock like go-sqlmock)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing code, but based on the error it sounds like you're sharing a connection between multiple tests, and each one is trying to start a transaction. Make sure that each test open its own connection, starts its own transaction, and when it is finished, commits or rolls back and closes the connection.

Comment: I added some example code. The problem is transaction doesn't work if I use transaction in the tested code(like `foo` function).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can doing integration testing using docker. Test directly to spawned container that has a active mysql.

You can use Test suite from testify.
Every time you test, run the docker container, and test it with a live mysql.

Comment: I have a mysql to use for testing. But it doesn't work. btw, I added some example code to explain my problem.

Comment: I see. Your solution is starting a new docker container for every test case. Right?

Comment: Yes... It will test directly with a live mysql

Comment: It should work, though I'm not sure wether there's a better way. I'll try it.

Comment: With Test suite of testify, you can just starting a single container for all test, no need starting new test for each test case

Comment: If I use just a single container for all tests, perhaps there'll be the problem described in my question: how to do cleanup rightly after every test case?

Comment: You can use DB migrations,  drop the db , each one test case passed, and migrate new Data for a new test case. Or you can reuse the existing data before.  

You can use https://github.com/mattes/migrate for helping DB migrate in your tests

the drawback is, it might not so fast as a simple test. Because you test directly into a live mysql.